# JMeter test report

Tags: jmeter, report

I'm using JMeter for integration and non-regression testing. 
The tests are automated and reports are working.

But since it is scenario testing and not performance testing the report doesn't give real business added value for that kind of tests.

My question: Is there any way to have a scenario (transaction controller based)reporting?

For the moment, to have some more meaningful result, transactions controllers and dummy sampler are used.

What we would like to have is the number of success/failure scenarios of the last test run. And also an history of success/failures per test run (1 by day).

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of getting the things done is putting your JMeter test under [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) orchestration so it will be automatically executed based on a [VCS hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) or according to the [Schedule](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Schedule+Build+Plugin)

Once done you will be able to utilize [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) which adds test results trends charts and ability to mark build as unstable/failed depending on various criteria.

Comment: Thank you, but sadly, we are not using Jenkins but Gitlab. I'll check if it is possible in Gitlab.

Comment: Gitlab is capable of displaying [JUnit-style reports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/junit_test_reports.html), you can consider running your test using [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/) as the wrapper, Taurus provides [JUnit XML Reporter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#JUnit-XML-Reporter) submodule which can convert your JMeter .jtl results file into JUnit-like report which can be used with GitLab. See [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) article for more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to create a suite based on particular test cases. like if single case include execution of more than 1 request in a single execution.
If this is the case, you can simple create a test fragment through jmeter gui, and copy all the samplers in single fragment.
Now to control their execution you can use any controller of your choice, i would suggest you to use module controller for http samplers.